# Mapping using imagesc and fixing axis

Tags: matlab

[bathymetry image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4GTp.png)[Bathymetry image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/190dy.png)HI I am trying to change the resolution of bathymetry (2041x1441) to fit with chlorophyll (960x348). I managed to do that using griddata in matlab, but now when i plot figure using imagesc the map is plotted on its side of upside down. am i doing something wrong?

below is a script that i tried.

```
clear all; close all;

fn='SA_OCCCI_Monthly_199801.nc';
chl_lat = ncread(fn, 'lat');
chl_lon = ncread(fn, 'lon');
chl_chla = ncread(fn, 'chlor_a');

chl_chl_a = fliplr(chl_chla);

[chl_lat2d,chl_lon2d] = meshgrid(chl_lat,chl_lon);

chl_lon_min = min(chl_lon2d(:));
chl_lon_max = max(chl_lon2d(:));
chl_lat_min = min(chl_lat2d(:));
chl_lat_max = max(chl_lat2d(:));

fn2='GEBCO_2019_20.0_-32.0_30.0_-38.0.nc';
bath_lon = ncread(fn2, 'lon'); bath_lon=fliplr(bath_lon);
bath_lat = ncread(fn2, 'lat'); bath_lat=fliplr(bath_lat);
bath_depth_orig= ncread(fn2,'elevation'); 
bath_depth=permute(bath_depth_orig,[2,1]);
bath_depth=flipud(bath_depth);

gridded_bath = griddata(bath_lon,bath_lat,bath_depth,chl_lon2d, 
chl_lat2d);
gridded_bath = flipud(gridded_bath);


shelf_bath=gridded_bath;
shelf_bath(gridded_bath>0 | gridded_bath<-200)=NaN;
shelf_bath = fliplr(shelf_bath);


figure;
subplot(2,2,1); imagesc(bath_lon,bath_lat,bath_depth'); colorbar;
subplot(2,2,2); imagesc(chl_lon,chl_lat,shelf_bath'); colorbar;
subplot(2,2,3); imagesc(chl_lon,chl_lat,chl_chl_a'); colorbar;
subplot(2,2,4); imagesc(chl_lon,chl_lat,gridded_bath'); colorbar;
```

the image i get in the end has the two maps on the right sideways.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?  I'm not sure what "on its side of upside down" means.  But you can flip the axes of your plots by removing the transpose operations in the last four lines.  It may also help to add "axis image" to flip the display direction of the y axis.

Comment: How do I attach an image here?

Comment: Hi nhowe, I have edited my question, image 1 is with transpose and image 2 is without the transpose.

Comment: I still can't tell which way the image is supposed to go.  But you should be able to orient each image in any direction you like with some combination of fliplr, flipud, transpose, axis ij and axis xy.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to correct it using fliplr(flipud(x)).